# rails 3 + jquery + ajax - dont discard flash upon ajax request which redirects

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, ruby-on-rails-3

Normally, I call flash.discard if my request is xhr. I do this as an after filter in the application controller.

However, I dont want to call flash.discard in the event that I have an ajax call which sets a flash and then redirects to another page.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you need to know if a response is a redirect. Create an after filter in application controller to check the response status.

```
after_filter :discard_flash_message

def discard_flash_message
  if request.xhr? and response.status == :found
    //do not call flash.discard
  end
end
```

Comment: Flash is discarded when there is a js redirect because js redirect is not actually a redirect. I am doing a js redirect window.location = <%= path %>.

Comment: moreover, if i redirect_to on an xhr request, the flash is discarded. following is my after filter code: flash.discard if (request.xhr? and response != :found)